# Check Ionic storage for item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I want to show intro slider when user just installed the app (only once)

## Logic

1. When user install the app store item named `intro` with value of `false`
2. When user open the app check `intro` item, if value is `false` show intro page if value is `true` continue with routing and load main page route.

## Issue

I have tried couple of ways to achieve this goal but all failed as result of storage not having any item named `intro`.

## Code

What I've tried so far: (all placed in `app.component.ts` file)

`1`

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private storage: NativeStorage,
  ) {
    this.letsTest();
  }

letsTest(){
    console.log('fired');

    if (this.storage.getItem('intro') == undefined) { // if not getting intro add and redirect to intro route
      this.storage.setItem('intro', false);
      this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/intro');
    } else { // otherwise do normal routing and load main page
      console.log('exists', this.storage.getItem('intro'));
    }
}
```

**Result**: Failed.

`2`

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private storage: NativeStorage,
  ) {
    this.letsTest();
  }

letsTest(){
    console.log('fired');
    //get intro
    const intro = this.storage.getItem('intro');
    // if not exist add it and reload to intro route
    if (!intro){
      console.log('intro was undefined so we set new false value in storage');
      this.storage.setItem('intro', false);
      this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/intro');
    } else {//if found get it and check value of it
      this.storage.getItem('intro').then(
        data=>{
          console.log('just data', data);
//if value is true means user already saw intro do normal routing and load main page
          if(data == true){
            console.log('exists', data);
          }else{
// if value is not true (false) then load intro page first
            this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/intro');
            console.log('ionViewWillEnter checked', data);
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log('some error happened', error);
        }
      )
    }
}
```

**Result**: Failed.

`Console debug`
This is what I get in console (Code 2 = ITEM_NOT_FOUND)

```
__zone_symbol__state: 0
__zone_symbol__value: NativeStorageError
code: 2
exception: null
source: "Native"
__proto__: Error
constructor: ƒ (code, source, exception)
ITEM_NOT_FOUND: 2
JSON_ERROR: 5
NATIVE_WRITE_FAILED: 1
NULL_REFERENCE: 3
UNDEFINED_TYPE: 4
WRONG_PARAMETER: 6
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 3
name: "NativeStorageError"
prototype: Error {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: NativeStorageError.js:6
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[1]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

## Question

How can I check `intro` item from native local storage and redirect user based on it's value?

Comment: you are using unblock function so use then and catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";
constructor( public storage: Storage){
this.storage.get('intro').then(value => {
      if(value){
     //nav to home page
      }else{
        this.setIntro(true)
      }
    },reason => {
      this.setIntro(true)
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })

}


  setIntro(bool:boolean){
    this.storage.set('intro',bool).then(()=>{
      //nav to intro page
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

Comment: does this `setIntro(bool:boolean){` fire only once or every time user open the app it sets `intro` value to `false`?

Comment: if the value is null or undefined it means false, So if the user opening the app for the first  time then it will be false. Then we are set intro to true so that when the user opens again then it will not goto Intro page.

Comment: it didn't work, I've made new app and it loads tab 1 directly (no error in console at all)

Comment: are you using device mobile ?

Comment: bcoz it native plugin

Comment: yes as I'm using native storage I have to build debug app to use storage and yes I've changed `set()` to `setItem()` and `get()` to `getItem()`

Comment: I mean you are using an android device to check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197975/discussion-between-aashay-karekar-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is likely something to do with you using `NativeStorage` instead of Ionic Storage, which is the recommended option.

There are several tutorials out there for this.

I think this is a good one:

- [Ionic Intro Slider for New Users | AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic4-intro-slides-tutorial-to-educate-app-users/)

That content is pro but you can get 3 free lessons, it was a bit confusing but refreshing the page got it loaded for me normally.

The idea is to use an Route Guard instead of doing it in the page. So you would generate a guard and use something like this inside of it:

```
// ...omitted
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TutorialGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private storage: Storage, private router: Router) {}

  async canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> {

    const isComplete = await this.storage.get('tutorialComplete');

    if (!isComplete) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/tutorial');
    }

    return isComplete;
  }
}
```

Then you can just put that guard on your homepage route like:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TutorialGuard } from './guards/tutorial.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule',
    canActivate: [TutorialGuard] // <-- apply here 
  },
  {
    path: 'tutorial',
    loadChildren: './tutorial/tutorial.module#TutorialPageModule'
  }
];
@NgModule(...)
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And in the tutorial / intro code you would set the `isComplete` value once the user reached the end of the intro slides:

```
  async finish() {
    await this.storage.set('tutorialComplete', true);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
```